# How to override text color for all websites (using userContent.css) in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, browser, css

Many websites—such as Google search results—display grey text on white background. On my display, the grey color is hard to see.

1. Can I override text color for **all websites**, without affecting anything else?
2. Can I override text color for google specifically?

I only want to affect color of text in the body, not the color of the hyperlinks.

I know, that I could change the color profile in Firefox:

```
Preferences
  -> Content
     -> Colors
```

and deselect "Allow pages to choose their own color", but that will mess up the whole webpage.

Can I force the text to be black for *all* websites by modifying `userContent.css` ?

Comment: So what do you want? What is wrong with the setting specified in the question? “Messes up” is not a problem description. What do you mean by overriding text color if not the thing that the setting causes?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela - it changes not just text color, but the whole page. It is easy to see it for yourself, if you change the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userContent.css` file is ideal for such customizations.

To reach the goal for your **point 1** (i.e. override the colors of all websites) use:

```
body {
  color: black !important;
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

Concerning your **point 2**:

To customize the output only of the Google search results, check which class the descriptive text of the search results belongs to (via "right mouse click -> inspect elemtent"):

[image]

You can see, the class is `.st`, so you can use the following code in `userContent.css` to override only the properties of that class, and only on google sites (the global `.com` site and -- in my case -- the regional `.de` site):

```
@-moz-document domain(google.de), domain(google.com) {
.st {
   color: black !important;
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

For illustration purposes I included a yellow background color directive, too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best and most evolved add-on to Firefox for changing the display of pages is
[Greasemonkey](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page). It can change any element on any page, including
HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

For more information see (but much more can be found via Google) :

[GreaseSpot wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page)
[Video tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311195810/http://codebazaar.blogspot.com/2010/11/monkey-see-greasemonkey-do.html)
[Scripts repository](http://wiki.greasespot.net/User_Script_Hosting)
[Change page styles with Greasemonkey](http://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/change-page-styles-with-greasemonkeytampermonkey/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds you changed your "brightness" to a value where grey is nearly white.

Maybe i'm missing the point. But maybe you have this Problem in ohter applications too.

I would try to change the contrast and/or gamma-settings for the display and/or the video-output.

Most modern graphic-drivers have the ability to change brightness, contrast and gamma. (Nvidia Control Center or ATI Catalyst Control Center)